# SQL command not properly ended with WHERE statement

Tags: sql, oracle

With this statement:

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) 
FROM STATION 
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) 
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

why do I get this error:

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended  SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) WHERE ROWNUM = 1

Comment: You might just try putting the order by clause last.

Comment: Order By should go after the Where clause

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
select * from (
    SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY)
) WHERE rownum = 1;
```

You have a syntax error in your query, because the `ORDER BY` comes after the `WHERE` clause. So, you'll have this after fixing the syntax error:

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) 
FROM STATION
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY)
```

If you recall, the `WHERE` clause is evaluated before the `ORDER BY` clause.
Since, [ROWNUM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/pseudocolumns008.htm)  pseudocolumn returns a number indicating the order in which Oracle selects the row from a table or set of joined rows. The first row selected has a `ROWNUM` of 1, the second has 2, and so on. the `ROWNUM` return values 1,2,3,... based on the order in which data from table `station` is fetched (could be in any order), which is probably not what you want.

If you embed the `ORDER BY` clause in a subquery and place the `ROWNUM` condition in the top-level query, then you can force the `ROWNUM` condition to be applied after the ordering of the rows.

So, you query becomes this:

```
select * from (
    SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY)
) WHERE rownum = 1;
```

In this, the rows are first sorted based on the length of content of CITY column inside the subquery, and then applies `ROWNUM` in the increasing order of the length of CITY column. So, now you can filter out the first row using `ROWNUM = 1` predicate.

Alternatively, in Oracle database 12c and above, you can use the [`FETCH FIRST N ROWS ONLY`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1) clause to make your life easier (no subquery required).

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) 
FROM STATION
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY)
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

This clause will be evaluated after the ordering is done and returns the top one row.

Comment: Adding a small explanation (of how rownum works and why having the WHERE condition in the same SELECT as the ORDER BY doesn't produce the desired result) would help make this a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an Oracle 12c, instead of `ROWNUM` you can also use a `FETCH FIRST` clause:

```
create table station (
  city varchar2(200)
);
insert into station (city) values ('New York');
insert into station (city) values ('Rio');
insert into station (city) values ('Tokyo');


select city, length(city)
from station
order by length(city)
fetch first 1 rows only
;
-- Rio 3
```

Especially if you don't want the first N rows ordered by some criterion, but the next N rows in a later call as well. Then `OFFSET x ROWS FETCH NEXT x ROWS ONLY` is easier to use than nested `ROWNUM`s, IMO.

See http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702 for details (Ctrl-F "row_limiting_clause").

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper syntax.

```
SELECT CITY, LENGTH(CITY) 
FROM STATION 
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
ORDER BY LENGTH(CITY) ;
```

Comment: Probably not what the OP wanted (if he wanted to get the longest city name).